Summary arrow is not centered with the content
I'm using summary/details html gadget for show a series of events.
Here is a simplified code (removed all rails/erb logic)


.eventscreen {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  gap: 1em;
  details {
    justify-self: center;
    table {
      display: inline;
      table-layout: auto;
      width: 70%;
    }
    td {
      border-right: 1px solid;
      text-align: center;
    }
  }
  summary {
    font-style: italic;
  }
  details[open] {
    padding: 0.5em;
  }
  details[open] summary {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #733030;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  }
}
<div class="eventscreen">
  <details class="box">
    <summary>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>name</th>
          <td>address</td>
          <td>date</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </summary>
    <div>
      descr
    </div>
  </details>
  <details class="box">
    <summary>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>name</th>
          <td>address</td>
          <td>date</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </summary>
    <div>
      descr
    </div>
  </details>
</div>



Also I want to replace the arrow with a PNG icon. I tried removing it with this, but it has no affect (in Chrome):
summary::-webkit-details-marker {display: none;}


May I ask why you have a <table> in your <summary>? To me it doesn't look like a good idea.

I'm working on a startup prototype. I use summary/detail gadget for show some events: in summary you see basic data in form of table: name, data, location. Clicking on it, you have details and note.
Sure it can be done in a trillion ways, this is a first easy running edition.

In reality the marker is centered vertically to the  element:

but the display property is not correct. Changing it to inline-block and setting vertical-align: middle in the same selector will make the marker centered vertically:

.eventscreen {
    & details {
        table {
            display: inline-block; /* changed from inline */
            vertical-align: middle; /* added */
            table-layout: auto;
            width: 70%;
        }
    }
}

To hide the marker and replace it with an image you can do the following:
summary {
  font-style: italic;
  list-style: none;
}

summary::before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  background: url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b94f537e4af21b0458d60f69003c7d58?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG);
  background-size: contain;
}



.eventscreen {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  gap: 1em;
  details {
    justify-self: center;
    table {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      table-layout: auto;
      width: 70%;
    }
    td {
      border-right: 1px solid;
      text-align: center;
    }
  }
  summary {
    font-style: italic;
    list-style: none;
  }
  summary::before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    background: url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b94f537e4af21b0458d60f69003c7d58?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG);
    background-size: contain;
  }
  details[open] {
    padding: 0.5em;
  }
  details[open] summary {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #733030;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  }
}
<div class="eventscreen">
  <details class="box">
    <summary>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>name</th>
          <td>address</td>
          <td>date</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </summary>
    <div>
      descr
    </div>
  </details>
  <details class="box">
    <summary>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>name</th>
          <td>address</td>
          <td>date</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </summary>
    <div>
      descr
    </div>
  </details>
</div>





You current issue is related to font-size of marker. To solve the issue, you can adjust the marker size to center the arrow relative to the surrounding text content like the below.



.eventscreen {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  gap: 1em;
  details {
    justify-self: center;
    table {
      display: inline;
      table-layout: auto;
      width: 70%;
    }
    td {
      border-right: 1px solid;
      text-align: center;
    }
  }
  summary {
    font-style: italic;

    &::marker {
      font-size: 1.5em;
    }
  }
  details[open] {
    padding: 0.5em;
  }
  details[open] summary {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #733030;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  }
}
<div class="eventscreen">
  <details class="box">
    <summary>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>name</th>
          <td>address</td>
          <td>date</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </summary>
    <div>
      descr
    </div>
  </details>
  <details class="box">
    <summary>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>name</th>
          <td>address</td>
          <td>date</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </summary>
    <div>
      descr
    </div>
  </details>
</div>




You can remove the default marker and use a png file or before instead of the marker.



.eventscreen {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  gap: 1em;
  details {
    justify-self: center;
    table {
      display: inline;
      table-layout: auto;
      width: 70%;
    }
    td {
      border-right: 1px solid;
      text-align: center;
    }
  }
  summary {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  summary::before {
    content: "▶";
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease;
    font-style: normal;
  }
  details[open] {
    padding: 0.5em;
  }
  details[open] summary::before {
    content: "▼";
  }
  details[open] summary {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #733030;
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  }
  details[open] summary::before {
    content: "▼";
  }
}
<div class="eventscreen">
  <details class="box">
    <summary>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>name</th>
          <td>address</td>
          <td>date</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </summary>
    <div>
      descr
    </div>
  </details>
  <details class="box">
    <summary>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>name</th>
          <td>address</td>
          <td>date</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </summary>
    <div>
      descr
    </div>
  </details>
</div>



Note: To remove the default marker, you can use list-style: none;

To center the arrow on the line, you can just give your tr element display:flex;
.eventscreen {
 ...

    tr {
      display: flex;
    
    }td {
        border-right: 1px solid;
        text-align: center;
    }}
}

To remove the details marker in Chrome you can set the list-style to none (your definition works for safari). Or use list-style-type to replace it with a custom character.
summary {
    font-style: italic;
    list-style: none;
    /* or: list-style-type: "+"; */
}

If you want to replace the marker with an image, you can define a background-image for the summary.

You should copy the demo snippet down here and show your solution.

Markers and Issues
The arrow on <summary> elements is a ::marker pseudo-element, which generates for list-item display properties. But working with markers is difficult for multiple reasons (non-exhaustive list):

Markers aren't fully styleable yet
It is difficult to center in flow layout, which a list-item display property enforces; this is <summary>'s default and required for markers
Using images with markers is more difficult than with other elements

Alternative: Pseudo-Elements
Instead you should use ::before pseudo-elements:


summary {
  list-style-type: none;
}
summary::before {
  /* Example: Black Right-Pointing Triangle */
  content: "\25b6";
}
<details>
  <summary>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>header cell</th>
        <td>data cell</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </summary>
  
  <div>Description</div>
</details>



Not using ::markers means we aren't limited to display property combinations with list-item. For example we may now use display: flex, which will make centering simpler:


summary {
  display: flex;
  /* No list-style-* properties needed without list-item */
}
summary::before {
  content: "\25b6";
}
<details>
  <summary>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>header cell</th>
        <td>data cell</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </summary>
  
  <div>Description</div>
</details>



When using pseudo-elements like ::before, you can use images with the content or (my preference) background-image property:


summary {
  display: flex;
}
summary::before {
  /* Example: 8x8 image */
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/7/8/8);
  content: ""; /* 'content' must still be specified! */
  /* You may have to (or want to) specify sizes explicitly */
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
}
<details>
  <summary>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>header cell</th>
        <td>data cell</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </summary>
  
  <div>Description</div>
</details>



As mentioned before, centering with flex layout is simple:


summary {
  display: flex;
}
summary::before {
  /* Set cross-axis (default: vertical) alignment to center */
  align-self: center; 
  content: "";
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/7/8/8);
}
<details>
  <summary>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>header cell</th>
        <td>data cell</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </summary>
  
  <div>Description</div>
</details>



Note: You can use absolute positioning to simulate a list-style-position of outside.

Here, the advantage of flex layout over flow layout for <summary> is, that its children (like <table>) are layed out as specified by the parent, instead of combinations of the parent's internal and the children's outside display property.
Tables are meant to display tabular data. A "half" table is not useful, and cannot be properly done in HTML. A (full) table usually contains detailed data, which can be summarized. A more fitting markup would thus be as follows:
<details>
  <summary>... (table summary)</summary>
  <table><!--... (table data)--></table>
</details>

This allows people to judge by the summary whether they are interested in taking a more detailed look at your table, while others can skip the conveniently closeable element with ease.
Based on your comment, it may look as follows:


<details>
  <summary>Events with location and date</summary>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Date</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Game Awards 2024</td>
        <td>Peacock Theater in L.A., CA, USA</td>
        <td>December 12, 2024</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lights All Night 2024</td>
        <td>Dallas Market Hall in Dallas, TX, USA</td>
        <td>December 28-29, 2024</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3" style="text-align:center">...</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</details>



Note: You may want to provide a better summary than my "events ..." (unless your webpage provides sufficient context!).
